Prove that $abcd=s^2$ implies this divisibility statement about $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-4s$
Summary
This is an attempt to knock this question into better shape and get some plausible conjecture out of it which has the backing of a non-trivial amount of searching for counterexamples.
In my notation (see below), that earlier question concerned $p=7$ specifically. I generalise to other primes $p$ and conjecture that the result, though not unique to $p=7$, is special to $p=3$ and $7$. That earlier question also concerned the parity of $k$ where $2^k\Vert r$. I couldn't find any relevance to this, so my problem statement doesn't mention it.
Problem statement
Let $p$ be a prime. Let $a, b, c, d, s$ be positive integers such that $abcd=s^2$. Let $r=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-4s$ and suppose further that $p\mid r$.
If $p=3$ or $7$, is it true that $p^2$ divides at least one of $a, b, c, d$ and $r$? Proof or counterexample, please.
Wlog $a\geqslant b\geqslant c\geqslant d$. For $p=3$ and $7$, I have checked up to $a=1000$ and not found any counterexamples. If there are any, it would be remarkable how high the lowest counterexamples are, given that for other primes $p$ there are many low counterexamples.
With some values for $p>7$ there are counterexamples where $p\Vert r$ but $p\nmid abcd$, e.g. $(a, b, c, d; r)=(22, 16, 11, 8; 221=13\cdot 17)$, $(12, 12, 4, 1; 209=11\cdot 19)$, $(27, 25, 16, 3; 899=29\cdot 31)$.
With $p=5$, the situation is different. The conjecture is false, but it seems that, in each counterexample, $5$ exactly divides (i.e. 5 divides but 25 doesn't) at least two of $a, b, c$ and $d$, e.g. $(a, b, c, d; r)=(10, 5, 2, 1; 90)$. Even there, $25\mid abcd$ so $5\mid s$. In contrast to where $p>7$, I haven't found any counterexamples where $5\nmid abcd$.
The situation with $p=2$ is similar to that with $p=5$. Credit to Mike for correcting my earlier erroneous statement with regard to $p=2$.

What about 1,1,2,2?  Then r=2 and nothing is a multiple of 4.

@Mike You are right. My program had a bug whereby it sought solutions to a problem closer to the one in the earlier question, and I wrongly thought it worked for my current one. I withdraw claims w.r.t. $p=2$.

one pattern is $(1,1,1,s^2)$   which gives $r = (s-1)(s^3 + s^2 + s - 3)$

another is $(1,1,s,s)$  which gives $r = 2(s-1)^2   .$  I am seeing lots of ways to get peculiar factors of $r$  that do not appear among $abcd$

the occurrences of $7$   dividing $r$   seem to be the second pattern only, $(1,1,s,s)$  where $s \equiv 1 \pmod 7$  so that $7^2$  does happen

higher bounds, when $7|r$  but not $49$  it is turning out that $7|s,$  so that $49 |abcd.$   So far one of $a,b,c,d$ is divisible by that $49$

a start:   take a prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$   Then $-1$ is not a quadratic residue. Thus there are no $x,y \neq 0 \pmod q$  with $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q$  Thus when $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$  it is not possible to have exactly two or three  of $a,b,c,d$  divisible by $q.$
